# Remember tabs (including cwd and tab title) between executions

Tags: windows-terminal

I cannot seem to find a way to make Windows Terminal remember all tabs after quitting it.
I also cannot find a way to specify multiple tabs in the settings.
Are these key feature really not available yet in Windows Terminal 1.1.2233 ?

Comment: Don't think it is possible at the moment but being tracked at: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported now!

To preserve tab titles just change the [launch mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/startup#launch-mode) setting.

Preserving CWD is also supported, but needs [some additional configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/new-tab-same-directory) to work.